# Angular: Cannot retrieve value of ng-model when ng-minlength is not satisifed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given:

```
<input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.fields.password" ng-minlength="8" />

{{ ctrl.fields.password.length }}
```

Nothing shows up until you've met the minimum length as required by the validation. That is, if the length of the password is less than 8, then the value of the model is `null`. Removing `ng-minlength` solves that problem.

This is quite unexpected behavior, as the validity of the field should have no bearing on the access to the model's value.

Is there a way to work around this in Angular 1.5? I want to show the user the length of their password as they type, but since the value is `null` until it's at least 8 characters, then I can't.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way Angular `$validators` work: if validatiion fails, value is not passed from view to model, and model is reset.

Here's a good introduction to how Angular built-in validation works:

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/11/exploring-angular-1.3-validators-pipeline.html

If you don't like this, [angular-ui-validate](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-validate) is a good package that works in a non-disruptive way (i.e. model is always updated and you decide on what to do with the validation result).